# How to enable AWS band on Galaxy s4 SGH-I337M?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

Phone stats:

Make:                  Samsung Galaxy s4
Model #:               SGH-I337M
Android Version:       5.0.1
Baseband Version:      I337MVLUGOH1
Kernel Verion:         3.4.0-4508315
                       DPI@SWHD7402 #1

Old Carrier:          Telus  (unlocked by carrier)
New carrier:          Wind mobile

Problem:

After researching web/youtube, I had bought the S4 on the premise that I could add the AWS band on to the phone with relative ease after watching a youtube video tutorial. (I'm not extremely technical but I'm a DIY guy and thought I could take on the challenge)

After purchasing the phone, I started following the steps in the video and quickly realized that the OS on the tutorial was older than my newly purchased phone with a updated OS. First video I found, told me to use a code *#7284# to enter into the modem settings (which no longer works for some reason). Then I found a video that asked me to enter *#0808# (this does work to get into the settings the tutorial asked me to change). The problem is, that after I change the settings from "MTP" to “RNDIS + DM + MODEM”, my phone will not connect to my computer and thus renders me unable to continue with the tutorial. (computer says "unable to identify USB connection")

I'm worried because I need to have my phone up and running before the end of this month because I have to return a shitty ACER phone I purchased temporarily from costco is running out of its 90 day return policy.

I know the phone is already 2 generations behind its predecessors but I'm hoping someone in this forum can help me out!

I've been following these steps: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2291589

Thank you in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 2):

In addition to changing from *#7284# to *#0808#, I also had to temporarily go back to the stock recovery from TWRP so that I can "enable cp logging".  If I don't do that, QPST (the program you have to run to add AWS) simply cannot find the connection to my phone.

Originally I was afraid that going back to the stock recovery would remove my root, and I would have to re-root again before I can install TWRP.  It turns out a non-issue.

Just a reminder when your attention is so warped up with this AWS challenge,  Odin cannot flash a recovery.img file (which you extract from the stock ROM).  I should have known better.  After some frustrating moment, I archived this file into the .tar format and Odin flashed it without a glitch.

Answer (score 0):

if you can find the exact carrier 4.4.2 file.. flash it with odin. the phone will take it no problem. then run rndis... but before you can try going into recovery and enable logging and see if that picks it up... im stuck on this problem right now and i know there is no way around it then to actually downgrade and push the aws file... good luck